# SQL Query - Join multiple fields to one record

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables (point and txt).
In table point an id is saved with a reference to a text in the table txt.

I would like to query the database and get a record from the point table where id is replaced with the text from the table txt.

I have this query now, but this will create 9 records for each record in the table point.

```
SELECT
   point.useradr, point.descr, point.plant, point.turnoff, point.position,
   point.instruction, point.restart, point.workcall, point.workinform, 
   point.offcall, point.offinform, point.procedur,
   txt.id, txt.txt
FROM point 
JOIN txt ON
   point.useradr = 'G2.F.22.CTS.CU0.90' AND
   ( point.plant = txt.id OR
     point.turnoff = txt.id OR
     point.position = txt.id OR
     point.instruction = txt.id OR
     point.restart = txt.id OR
     point.workcall = txt.id OR
     point.workinform = txt.id OR
     point.offcall = txt.id OR
     point.offinform = txt.id OR
     point.procedur = txt.id )
 ORDER BY txt.id
```

Comment: You are getting multiple matches to the text table.  You need some criteria to select one record from the matches available if you do not want to duplicate the point data rows for each match.  Typical is based on a max value or most recent date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To confirm my clarification, it SOUNDS like your "point" table acts like an item that has many components to it.  Each component points to a lookup table "txt" which has IDs and corresponding texts.  So one "point" record will have, in this case, 10 words displayed.

You can do with multiple left-joins and applying alias, or a single join, but applying aggregate group by per single point ID record which is not specifically listed.  Something like below with group by

```
SELECT
      P.id,
      MAX( P.useradr ) UserAdr, 
      MAX( P.descr ) Descr, 
      MAX( case when T.ID = P.plant then T.txt end ) as PlantDescrip, 
      MAX( case when T.ID = P.turnoff then T.txt end ) as TurnOffDescrip, 
      MAX( case when T.ID = P.position then T.txt end ) as PositionDescrip, 
      MAX( case when T.ID = P.instruction then T.txt end ) as InstructionDescrip, 
      MAX( case when T.ID = P.restart then T.txt end ) as RestartDescrip, 
      MAX( case when T.ID = P.workcall then T.txt end ) as WorkCallDescrip,
      MAX( case when T.ID = P.workinform then T.txt end ) as WorkInFormDescrip, 
      MAX( case when T.ID = P.offcall then T.txt end ) as OffCallDescrip, 
      MAX( case when T.ID = P.offinform then T.txt end ) as OffInFormDescrip, 
      MAX( case when T.ID = P.procedur then T.txt end ) as ProcedurDescrip
   from 
         point P
            join txt T
               ON T.id IN ( P.plant, P.turnoff, P.position,
                     P.instruction, P.restart, P.workcall,
                     P.workinform, P.offcall, P.offinform, P.procedur)
   where
      P.useradr = 'G2.F.22.CTS.CU0.90' 
   group by
      P.id
   order by 
      P.id
```

by using multiple joins since the Point "text Id" column link will exist or not, 
doing left join would look like

```
SELECT
      P.id,
      P.useradr, 
      P.descr, 
      ByPlant.txt as PlantDescrip, 
      ByTurnOff.txt as TurnOffDescrip, 
      ByPosition.txt as PositionDescrip, 
      ByInstruction.txt as InstructionDescrip, 
      ByRestart.txt as RestartDescrip, 
      ByWorkcall.txt as WorkCallDescrip,
      ByWorkinform.txt as WorkInFormDescrip, 
      ByOffcall.txt as OffCallDescrip, 
      ByOffinform.txt as OffInFormDescrip, 
      ByProcedur.txt as ProcedurDescrip
   from 
         point P
            Left JOIN txt ByPlant
                ON P.Plant = ByPlant.ID
            Left JOIN txt ByTurnOff
                ON P.turnoff = ByTurnOff.ID
            Left JOIN txt ByPosition
                ON P.position = ByPosition.ID
            Left JOIN txt ByInstruction
                ON P.instruction = ByInstruction.ID
            Left JOIN txt ByRestart
                ON P.restart = ByRestart.ID
            Left JOIN txt ByWorkcall
                ON P.Workcall = ByWorkcall.ID
            Left JOIN txt ByWorkinform
                ON P.Workinform = ByWorkinform.ID
            Left JOIN txt ByOffcall
                ON P.Offcall = ByOffcall.ID
            Left JOIN txt ByOffinform
                ON P.Offinform= ByOffinform.ID
            Left JOIN txt ByProcedur
                ON P.Procedur = ByProcedur.ID
   where
      P.useradr = 'G2.F.22.CTS.CU0.90' 
   order by 
      P.id
```